# Inequalities involving exponentials

Tags: inequality

I am having trouble to solve this inequality in specific.

For $f(x)=6-2^x$ and $g(x)=4^x$

Solve in $\mathbb{R}$:
$$
(f+g)(x)<6
$$

Comment: Please include your own effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Let $t=2^x$ and solve $6-t+t^2<6$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, I was doing the variable exchange wrong, Your hint help me solving the rest of the exercise.
Later I had to use the only possible value for y => 2^x=1 <=> x=0
 The answer is ]-infinite;0[

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: @GiuR  Well done! Your final result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
(f+g)(x) &< 6 \iff \quad \text{using the definitions}\\
6 - 2^x + 4^x &< 6 \iff \quad \text{subtracting $6$ from both sides} \\
-2^x + 4^x &< 0 \iff \quad \text{adding $2^x$ to both sides} \\
4^x &< 2^x \iff \quad \text{splitting $4^x=(2^2)^x = 2^{2x} = (2^x)^2$} \\
2^x 2^x &< 2^x \iff \quad \text{dividing both sides by $2^x \ne 0$} \\
2^x &< 1 \iff \quad \text{property of exponential functions $b^x$} \\
x &< 0
\end{align}